# Multiple copy of file by using threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, copy

I have a simple program. She makes multiple copy of the selected file. Explain to me, please, how can I speed up the copy process by using threads?

//Main class (interface):

```
public class Main extends JFrame{
    static JButton bt1, bt2, bt3;
    static JLabel lb1, lb2, lb3;
    static JTextField tf1;
    static int copyCount;
    eHandler handler = new eHandler();
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Main m = new Main("заголовок");
        m.setVisible(true);
        m.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        m.setSize(150, 100);
        m.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        m.setResizable(false);
    }

    public Main(String s){
        super(s);
        setLayout (new GridLayout(3, 1, 1, 1));
        bt1 = new JButton("Open file");
        bt2 = new JButton("Copy file");
        tf1 = new JTextField(5);
        add(bt1);
        add(bt2);
        add(tf1);
        bt1.addActionListener(handler);
        bt2.addActionListener(handler);
    }
}

class eHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource()==Main.bt1){
            OpenFile op = new OpenFile();
            op.fileOpen();
        }

        if (e.getSource()==Main.bt2){
            Main.copyCount = Integer.parseInt(Main.tf1.getText());
            Copy cop = new Copy();
            cop.fileCopy();
        }
    }
}
```

//The procedure for opening a file:

```
public class OpenFile {
    JFileChooser chooser1;
    static File fileDat;
    static String fileName, filePath, fileFullPathName;

    public void fileOpen(){
        try {
            chooser1 = new JFileChooser();
            chooser1.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
            chooser1.setDialogTitle("Выберите файл");
            chooser1.showOpenDialog(null);
            fileDat  = chooser1.getSelectedFile();
            fileName = fileDat.getName();
            filePath = fileDat.getParent();
            fileFullPathName = fileDat.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

//The procedure for copying a file:

```
public class Copy {
    static String copyfileFullPathName[];
    public void fileCopy(){
    copyfileFullPathName = new String [Main.copyCount];
        for(int i=0; i<Main.copyCount; i++){
            copyfileFullPathName [i] = OpenFile.filePath+"\\"+i+".txt";
            try {
                Files.copy(Paths.get(OpenFile.fileFullPathName), Paths.get(copyfileFullPathName [i]));
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably can't speed this up using multiple threads. The copying of a file is going to be "I/O bound", meaning that the limiting factor in the speed is how fast you can write bytes to the device. For hard disk drives, this is a serial operation; different threads cannot do it at the same time, one thread would have to wait until the disk was free to do its writing (on a different place on the disk), and so there would be, at least, no speed improvement.

And in fact, this is a classic case of making something worse while trying to improve it. Since the longest operation is liable to be the disk positioning its read/write head over the place needed for the write, putting the writes on multiple threads is likely to cause MORE of that operation that a single thread, since single write operations of a longer length can be optimized by the disk drivers to be faster than multiple shorter operations.

If you're certain this will only be used on solid-state drives, then different parameters apply. But things don't get faster just because they're in different threads.

--

edit: I suppose you could investigate using larger buffers for your file operations; sometimes that speeds things up.